# How to Change a .PNG file name through Java/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rename

I was wondering if anyone can help me solve this. I want to change/rename the name of a file .png as soon as I create it using java Eclipse through Linux. So when the file is saved into a folder I want the user to be able to change the name of it to whatever the user wants. How do I do that?
Here is my code...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class adbPicture implements ActionListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


// exec.(points at whatever .sh file you want to run in the folder)
try {
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/local/ANT/arthm/Desktop/stuff/pics1.sh);
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(             proc.getInputStream()));
try {
proc.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
while (read.ready()) {
System.out.println(read.readLine());
}
} catch (IOException e) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error 5! You Messed Up!");
}



int picreply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to change the name?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(picreply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
String namestuff = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Input Name"); 

// Here in this area is where I want to add the code to change the name of the file...
}
else {
System.exit(0); // also this makes me exit the whole program, how do I only exit the //showConfirmDialog box?

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String fileRenamed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Input New Name"); 


Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv "+ pathToFile+namestuff+" "+pathToFile+fileRenamed);
```

Comment: @ anguyen; in .exec("mv "+ pathToFile+namestuff+" "+pathToFile+fileRenamed);  // due I create a new variable called //pathToFile? or do I put the actual Path to the file? and if I put //the actual path, I might need to use "" parentheses?

Comment: pathToFile is just a mock, you have to replace with your correct path to the file. The pat to the file is a string so it must be inside two double quotes.

Comment: yes, this requires pathToFile to be a valid path to the file.

Side-note: nameStuff is not a reasonable variable name in this (or any) scenario. There are multiple names that need to be managed and it is very hard to tell which is the new name and which is the old name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`File#renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

```
File original = new File("...");
original.renameTo(new File("..."));
```

Note.  If you change the location that the file is stored in, this will act like a move

Comment: in new File("..."); Will this allow to input his/her own name of the file? Also, should I input the name of the old file? in new File("...");

Comment: Yes. The String parameter will be the path/file name for the file in question. If you only pass the name, it be renamed to the current working directory